# Laravel 4 authentication logout error

Tags: authentication, laravel, laravel-routing

I'm working on a log-in/log-out authentication routine for my Laravel 4 project and have hit a snag on log-out.

I've got a user table set up with username, email and password (as well as id and the timestamps columns). If I browse to a protected page, I can log in fine with the system dialog, but logging out generates an error. Here are my relevant routes:

```
        Route::get('/logout', function()
    {
        Auth::logout();
        return View::make('logout');
    });

    Route::get('spotlight', array(
        'before' => 'auth.basic' ,
        function()
    {
        return View::make('spotlight');
    }
    ));
```

And here's the error I get when I go to /logout:

```
[2014-05-29 17:33:56] production.ERROR: exception 'Illuminate\Database\QueryException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'remember_token' in 'field list' (SQL: update `users` set `updated_at` = 2014-05-29 17:33:56, `remember_token` = KiZHAYFKZnr0qwntsu0FhXWdwS37KkaQO1omS1OTnJ6DjpbmU9QXQenS7uGc where `id` = 1)' in /Users/jlowery/authapp/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php:555
```

Where should remember_token be? I have set up a sessions table, but it doesn't have such a column. Any ideas on where I'm going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't updated to version >=4.1.26 correctly.

You need to add a `remember_token` to your users table and update your `User` model if you are using the Eloquent authentication driver.

Read the [upgrade guide](http://laravel.com/docs/upgrade#upgrade-4.1.26) at Laravel docs for more details.

Comment: Aha! That worked. So, if I had run composer update and installing Laravel for my project, would that have included the user model updates?

Comment: no. you ran composer update, but you had to make some manual adjustments. It was a "breaking" update due to a security issue that had to be fixed. It had to be done manually.

Comment: Thanks - I have a related problem with login - I'll post another question and hope you can take a look.